# Fwrite doesn't work properly

Tags: c

Sorry for having this program in my native language, but I really can't seem to find why it doesn't work. So, I tested and the values of the a array are all correctly read, but when I try to look at the .dat file there is only the first word read in the for function ( a[0].marca ).

Here is the input [I also tested to see if it reads correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAONC.png)

Here is the .dat file [It only writes the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdMXg.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data
{
    int anul;
    int luna;
};
typedef struct data DATA;
struct automobil
{
    char marca[20];
    char carburant;
    char model[5];
    DATA fabricatie;
};
typedef struct automobil AUTOMOBIL;




int main()
{
    AUTOMOBIL a[100];
    int n;
    FILE *f;

    int i;
    if((f=fopen("evidenta.dat","wb"))==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Cate automobile sunt ?"); scanf("%d",&n);  // The number of cars registered
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)   // getting the details about every car
    {
        printf("\nMarca ? : "); fflush(stdin); gets(a[i].marca);
        printf("\nCarburant ? : "); fflush(stdin); getch(a[i].carburant);
        printf("\nModelul? :");  fflush(stdin); gets(a[i].model);
        printf("\nLuna fabricatie ? :"); scanf("%d",&a[i].fabricatie.luna);
        printf("\nAn fabricatie ? : "); scanf("%d",&a[i].fabricatie.anul);

        // After getting a line it has to write it in the binary file
        fwrite(&(a[i]),sizeof(AUTOMOBIL),1,f); //It writes only  a[0].marca
    }
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("\n %s",a[i].marca);
    printf("\n %c",a[i].carburant);
    printf("\n %s",a[i].model);
    printf("\n %d",a[i].fabricatie.luna);
     printf("\n %d",a[i].fabricatie.anul);
}

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Of course it does, it's your program surely that doesn't. 1. Please don't write 3 statements in a single line it's very ugly and hard to read. 2. Don't `fflush(stdin)`, `fflush()` is for output streams not input. 3. NEVER use `gets()` it's a deprecated function and it's very dangerous use `fgets()` instead. 4. Always check the return value of `scanf()`, it might be that it failed and your program is invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: How are you looking at the file?

Comment: I opened the .dat file inside codeblocks. And I tested to see if the a[i] values are all correct, they were... I know I'm using some outdated functions, but the reading part worked

Comment: `getch` is in `conio.h`, although that isn't included here that I can see.

Comment: @iharob: Actually, `gets` is not even part of C standard (anymore).

Comment: `getch` is no standard function. Use `getchar`.

Comment: @iharob Just for the sake of precision  `fflush on input stream is an extension to the C standard` for MS (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/9yky46tz.aspx) ;-)

Comment: Also suggest `fopen("evidenta.dat","wb")` --> `fopen("evidenta.dat","w")`  (drop b)

Comment: @Frankie_C I know but it's wise to teach people not to use it because it's not standard, it actually contradicts the standard.

Comment: Need to post example input data. `gets(a[i].model` does not protect against buffer over-runs.  So entering something like "abcde" will mess up the program.

Comment: Using `&a` is wrong (on the fwrite line), `a` is an array, just use `fwrite(a, ... )`

Comment: `getch(a[i].carburant);` is very wrong.  Expect something like `a[i].carburant = getch();`

Comment: yes, thank you, changed the getch part, but still the fwrite doesn't work, will post in 1 minute an example

Comment: Posted the pics, the only part that seems to not do it's job now, it's still the fwrite since I can't see the whole .dat file

Comment: "break" does not fit in `model[5];`.  Need 6

Comment: Hang on - what are you opening the file with to check its contents?

Comment: Open it with a hex editor, and tell us the file size/length.

Comment: Then try writing the lot, eg, sizeof(a), just to be sure of what's happening.

Comment: Screen shot does not match code.  Where do the lines `bmw\nb\n...1952\n" come from?

Comment: ..because I'm not convinced that the codeblocks editor is showing you what is there, binary-wise.  It's a text editor.

Comment: @MartinJames the file is 82 bytes , i opened it in a hex editor, should I print out what it says ?

Comment: @chux i added the later code, it was writing to see if the input was correct

Comment: Oh sh... no fclose(), as posted by @vVasfed:(

Comment: Code does not use end of line in saving to the file

Comment: Code is writing in blocks of `AUTOMOBIL` and OP is attempting to read it with a text editor.  Either write as text or view data with a data editor.

Comment: @Speedy.RoGamer sounds about right for two records: (20+1+5+8+8)*2 is around 82 bytes-ish.  Not sure of padding, int size etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, the codeblocks simply could not read the file in the correct way. I did an fread and it showed the right data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
fwrite(&(a[i]),sizeof(AUTOMOBIL),1,f);
```

Alternatively you can do that outside the loop:

```
fwrite(a,sizeof(AUTOMOBIL),n,f);
```

Also don't forget to fclose.

Comment: How about `fwrite(&(a[i]),sizeof a[i],1,f);`?

Comment: What is teh written file size in bytes?

Comment: Did you close the file?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you write the first item each time - `&a` while expecting `&(a[i])` to be written.

And do not forget to `fclose` the file after writing for the buffer not to be lost.

If you want to see the live changes on the file while you write, you need to disable output buffer `setbuf(f,NULL)` or flush it `fflush(f)`.

Comment: What is teh written file size in bytes?

Answer (score 0):

As the others answer say you need to write to `&a[i]`. If you want to see the contents of the file in the moment is written, you need to disable output buffer with `setbuf(f, NULL)` or flush it each time you write with `fflush(f)`.